# Spacy NLP with data from a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, spacy

I have a large pandas data frame of survey string responses, and we would like to trial some features of Spacy's NLP. We are just exploring the capabilities at the moment, but struggling with how to format the data into a format that works with the nlp function of spacy.

Eventually we would like to be able to look at popular topics in the string responses against their user data.

How do I run the nlp pipeline on a column of a dataframe? Or am I going around this the wrong way?

Comment: Can you let us know the error you are getting?

Answer (score 7):

You begin by calling `spacy.load()` with a language model. This will, depending on which model you choose, load tokenizer, tagger, parser, NER and word vectors for the language of your choice. This is stored in a variable called `nlp` in the `spaCy` [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/models).

```
nlp = spacy.load(language_model)
```

We can now call `nlp()` with any type of text string. So why does not: `nlp(df['column_with_strings'])` work? Because `df['column_with_strings']` is not a string, it is a `pandas.Series`:

> TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got Series)

So what you need to do is call `nlp()` on each value in the `pandas.Series`. You can do this by constructing a function and using `df['column_with_strings'].apply()` or by iterating over each row in the series.

Answer (score 5):

There is a more efficient and quick way to parse a Series with texts with the `nlp` pipeline by spaCy. SpaCy suggests using `nlp.pipe()` when processing large volumes of text.

Following the instructions that are given in the [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines) you can do the following:

```
texts = dataframe['series_with_text]
```

(Make sure that you have converted the type of the values into strings and you have removed any NaN values that might exist in your data frame).

Then:

```
docs = list(nlp.pipe(texts))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used list comprehension on a column of dataframe to gets vectors of text of each rows with the following code:

```
tweet_text = [[nlp(token).vector_norm for token in text.split()] for text in tweet_df_multi['tweet_text']]
```

but the problem is I'm values values with a comma(,).